# getting HttpResponse of the URL already loaded in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an `URL` `https://abc.myclient.com:9824/whatido/SSOServlet` which is launched in `webview`. This `URL` checks if the user is not authenticated, then redirected to login page. Once the authentication is done on login page , sends the response back to `https://abc.myclient.com:9824/whatido/SSOServlet` which further executes a javascript to redirect to `https://abc.myclient.com:9824/whatido/doneWithSSO.html` . I want to read the response from `https://abc.myclient.com:9824/whatido/SSOServlet` page, how do I read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) with your WebView. Take a look at 
`shouldInterceptRequest`, and note that there is one version for API < 21, and a different one for API 21+

Comment: i have `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` implemented, but it only gives me data for last URL loaded in webview.

Comment: two different methods - shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not shouldInterceptRequest

Comment: I figured out different way to get this response rather than in particular webview screen.